# Showing Array data

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach below that when `print_r` or `var_dumped` it shows the correct data but once I put the `$finalMenuDetails` into the location I need it shows `Array` and not the list.

**Var_dump**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Item 1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "item 2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "item 3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "23"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "90"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "23"
}
```

**PHP**

```
foreach($menuDetailsItem as $key => $value)
{
    $finalMenuDetails[] = $value. " ".$amount[$key] . '<br/>';
}
```

**Process:**

```
$menuName              = $_POST['menu'];
    $menuDetailsItem       = $_POST['item'];
    $menuDetailsItemAmount = $_POST['amount'];

    $menuResult = '';
    foreach ($menuDetailsItem as $key => $value) {
        $menuResult .= $value." ".$menuDetailsItemAmount[$key]."<br/>";
    }

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {   
        $to = "";
        $subject = "Booking";
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" . //header("Location: http://redherringcatering.co.nz/Thankyou.html");
        $message = "\n" . "<strong>NAME:</strong>    ". $varName . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>CONTACT:</strong>     " . $varContact . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>EMAIL:</strong>    ". $varEmail . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>COMPANY:</strong>     ". $varCompany . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>No. ATTENDING:</strong>    ".$varAttending . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DATE:</strong>    ". $varFunction . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DAY:</strong>     ". $varFunctionDay . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>DATE ORDERED:</strong>  ". $varOrdered . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>TIME REQUIRED:</strong>     ". $varTime . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>ONSITE:</strong>  ". $varOnsite . ", ". $varOnsite2 . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>INVOICE TO:</strong>     ". $varInvoice . "<br />" . "<br />" ."<strong>ADDRESS:</strong>\n". $varAddress . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>SPECIAL NEEDS:</strong>   ". $varSpecial . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>ORDER DETAILS:</strong><br/><br/>".  $menuName . "<br/>"."<br/>"."<strong>Items:</strong><br/><br/>".print_r($menuResult) . "\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `print_r` or `var_dump` result of your arrays, as well as your desired output? Somewhere you are concatenating an array object into your string instead of a value within the array.

Comment: perhaps you want `$finalMenuDetails .=`

Comment: @Cory Done I am wanting Item 1 23 etc

Comment: @Dagon I have done the .= and I am still getting Array

Comment: you are echoing `$finalMenuDetails` and not `$menuDetailsItem` ?

Comment: @Dagon Correct see that they are joined in the foreach

Comment: demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0dR9Wz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$item = array("item 1","item 2","item 3") ;
$amount = array("23","90","23") ;
$result_array = '';
foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    $result_array .= $value." ".$amount[$key]."<br/>";
}
print_r($result_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
item 1 23
item 2 90
item 3 23
```

Comment: The final result is going into an email how can I make it so that I can print it but now show it on the final page?

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the form while sending it through email?

Comment: Correct thats what I am trying to do

Comment: U can maintain the line breaks by using [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: in my email code I have `"<strong>Items:</strong><br/><br/>".$finalMenuDetails .` and it shows Array in the email

Comment: Have you tried the answer I've posted! It shouldn't return an Array.

Comment: In the email I get https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tuzzzpaoxdl2bo/Screenshot%202014-07-29%2010.17.18.png on the website I get the result I want in the email - https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhmbdo9ggeq17ru/Screenshot%202014-07-29%2010.17.37.png

Comment: Can you post part where you pass `$finalMenuDetails` var into mail ?

Comment: You need to replace : `"<strong>Items:</strong><br/><br/>".print_r($menuResult) . "\n"` with just `"<strong>Items:</strong><br/><br/>".$menuResult . "\n"`

Comment: Thanks @SpencerX Swear I did that and it didnt work - Thank You!

Comment: Anytime @JessMcKenzie :)